# Omitting Primary Key from PHP MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small PHP Mysql function which generates all the columns within a mysql table, but I would like the function not to display the primary keys for each table just the other columns.

How can this be done, I havent been able to find the code for it.

Thanks

It seems I didnt explain the question well.

The mysql table from which the columns are generated is sent on demand from a list of ALL THE TABLE IN THE DB (over 150) and I cant specify the exact columns for each of the table.

It would just be more efficient if I found a way of omitting the primary key from the result.

Since it isnt required for the subsequent processing and quite confusing to the enduser as to its use.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

`SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table`

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, returning the PK or not isn't going to break the bank.

In general, doing `SELECT * FROM` is bad, but if you're just going to do `SELECT every, column, but, the, pk FROM` then you may as well just select everything.

The best answer is just to SELECT the columns you need. If you need 3 columns, query for 3 columns and name them explicitly: `SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table_name`